# android Toolbar appbarlayout

Tags: android, toolbar, statusbar, android-appbarlayout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".Activity_Compose">

 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
     android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgComposeCancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/min_padding"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/exit" />

        <com.example.CustomTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Compose"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/min_textsize"
            app:font="@string/montserrat_regular" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center|right">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgComposeAttach"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/min_padding"
                android:contentDescription="@string/image"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/mail_attach" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgComposeSend"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/min_padding"
                android:contentDescription="@string/image"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/mail_send" />

        </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

      <include
         android:id="@+id/layout_dash_child"
         layout="@layout/act_compose_view" />


   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

included layout is here

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_compose">




     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|start"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/most_min_padding"

        android:weightSum="2">


        <com.example.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtComposeTo"
            style="@style/label_text_secondary_compose_mail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.85"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="@string/to"
            app:font="@string/montserrat_light" />

        <com.doodle.android.chips.ChipsView
            android:id="@+id/chipsView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/cstmBtnAddStaff"
            app:cv_max_height="130dp"
            app:cv_vertical_spacing="2dp" />

        <com.example.CustomButton
            android:id="@+id/cstmBtnAddStaff"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/cstmBtnAddStaff"
            android:text="+"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:font="@string/montserrat_regular" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.1dp"
        android:background="@color/not_black" />


    <com.example.CustomEditText
        android:id="@+id/txtComposeSubjectContent"
        style="@style/label_text_secondary_compose_mail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:hint="Subject"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/editor"
        android:padding="@dimen/most_min_padding"

        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_color"
        app:font="@string/montserrat_light"
        app:met_hideUnderline="true" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

[image: why this type of behaviour happening]

My toolbar went to behind to the status bar. i need to get rid of this issue. Helps will be upvoted.i added the students and after click the txtComposeSubjectContent edittext , all the layout including toolbar have gone to under the status bar. what is appening here. i dont added any styles here.

Comment: why are you appying tag like tools:targetApi="lollipop" in toolbar

Comment: for elevation="2dp"

Comment: try removing that tag

Comment: removed . not working

Comment: add android:fitsSystemWindows="true" in CoordinatorLayout

Comment: already tried not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128446/discussion-between-seventh-and-rahul-khurana).

Comment: @Seventh For a testcase can u comment views which are inside the Toolbar tag keep only simple TextView and check once?

Comment: Imageview, textview and one linearlayout which has two imageview with horozontan orientation.it is MI Max mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem relies on the Height provided for AppBarLayout and Toolbar, it picks a height from styles, try using wrap_content if you dont mind a really big toolbar.

Other approach could be to override the styles for AppBarLayout and/or Toolbar and play around with standard padding / margins.

For Example:

```
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="padding">8dp</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/tab_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

As you can see here im changing the standard padding for the AppBar Layout and providing custom size and color for the text of some tabs I got inside the AppBar.

If none of this works let the code as you got it at first and try on different devices, if your problem persists this happens because youre using a custom View inside the toolbar and the onDraw() methods collide posibly because of an incorrect onMeasure() method, if you really want to hold on on this approach you will have a lot of trouble. i think youre doing this because you want the coordinatorLayout behaviour, if you dont mind explain what u want to achieve and we could provide different approaches.

Comment: i think it is not height issue, it is like scrolling issue. the layout went behind to the status bar.